# Can we install Firebug for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firebug

I already installed Firebug in Firefox. Now I tried to install it on Chrome, I can't find fire bug

Comment: You can install firebug lite in chrome.

Comment: Chrome has the web inspector tools already.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Downgrading your Chrome Browser May help!!

Comment: Meh. This is how you get viruses

Answer (score 2):

It does not exist on Chrome,

Nor should you install Firebug on Firefox

> Firebug is a discontinued free and open-source web browser extension for Mozilla Firefox that facilitated the live debugging, editing, and monitoring of any website's CSS, HTML, DOM, XHR, and JavaScript.

Comment: You can install it still, but it’s unlikely the OP would need it when chrome comes with a more comprehensive dev tool.